# A file input button for all browsers, is this possible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload, uploadify

Is it possible to use **uploadify** to allow any user to select a file from the file dialogue and insert it into the file input element of a form? I only need to use uploadify as a way to style the "upload button" as an image.

I have tried other approaches [here](http://demo.mamuso.net/0002_jquery.prettyfile.html), [here](http://www.wnas.nl/demo/inputfile/) and [here](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/filestyle/demo.html). All are not compatible with all browsers.

What else can I use / do to have my file input element as an image?

I would like to have my file input button to look consistent in all browsers.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I can't remember the source of the technique but [this](http://jsfiddle.net/CyPJJ/6/) seems to be cross-browser. Tested in:

- Google Chrome 9
- FireFox 3.6
- Internet Explorer 6-9
- Opera 10
- Safari for Windows

Here is the complete code:

HTML:

---

```
<div>
    <button><!-- this is skinnable -->Pick a file ...</button>
    <input type="file" />
</div>
```

CSS:

---

```
div
{
    position:relative;
    width: 100px;
    height: 30px;
    overflow:hidden;
}

div button
{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

div input
{
    font: 500px monospace; /* make the input's button HUGE */
    opacity:0; /* this will make it transparent */
    filter: alpha(opacity=0); /* transparency for Internet Explorer */
    position: absolute;  /* making it absolute with z-index:1 will place it on top of the button */
    z-index: 1;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    padding:0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

The idea is to make the `<input type="file" />` transparent and place it on top of some style-able content (a `<button>` in this case). When the end user clicks the button she will actually click the `<input type="file" />`.

Comment: Hmmm very clean solution. Seems to work among the aforementioned browsers. Will test this further, but so far looking good. Thanks for that Atanas. Appreciate it

Comment: Used this before and it works pretty well. You can also use an onchange event on the input[file] to read the file path and display it back to the user in the UI. I used this for the compressor mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23745/does-a-yui-compressor-gui-app-exist/5056975#5056975)

Comment: As a reference, I found a few sources online in relevance to the solution mentioned above: http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/inputfile.html and http://hiox.org/30547-css-style-input-typefile-tags.php for anyone who wants to do further reading

Comment: But after I select a file, the top input box remains empty.  Using the browser to dynamically remove opacity=0, I see the file text is there.  Does someone have a technique to get the file name into the top box?

Comment: This almost worked for me out of the box. The click event on the input would fire but the file dialog would not open. I was able to fix this by removing the z-index (the button still remained on top of the input with or without it). I think it had something to do with the fact that the control was inside a jquery dialog. Hope that helps someone.

Comment: This really helped me and worked out of the box, however I am wondering why the need for making the input 500px? It appears to be perfect size but that part just doesn't make since to me. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The simple way to use a "label" tag and "for" property. Like this http://jsfiddle.net/Txrs6/ but in this case we don't see a chosen file.
CODE

```
<label for="inputFile" class="col-sm-3" style="padding-left: 0px;"><a class="btn btn-info">Выбрать...</a></label>`

<input style="display: none;" type="file" id="inputFile">
```

Another way with js http://jsfiddle.net/PZ5Ep/

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet in that case would be to use a flash uploader. This would introduce a complete separate control and would have no dependency on the browser. There are plenty of them on the net. Here's one : http://swfupload.org/

Comment: JohnP, I have listed a few on my initial post that are like swfupload. The problem is still the same, as explained with the uploadify method.

Comment: The link I posted actually uses Flash and has JS as a fallback only. Flash will look consistent on all browsers. Have a look

Comment: Im not looking to submit the form via Ajax though. You are right in the sense that Flash will make the file input look consistent. But Flash submits in its own way via Ajax

Comment: Yeah this uses asynchronous file uploads

Answer (score 0):

If it's only the upload button you want to style, why can't you use CSS? That should work across all browsers.

If you put your code on jsFiddle, I can tell you more about what you can do.

Comment: Hi Picardo, in theory, I'd like to use an image instead of the native file input element that is shown in all browsers. I believe CSS alone can't remove the text box that comes with the file input element

Comment: Which browsers are you having trouble with? You can use one of the options you cited and find a work around for the non-supporting browser.

Comment: Haven't tested on IE. But http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/filestyle works on FF, Chrome, Safari. It doesn't work at all with Opera

Comment: All browsers place severe constraints on how input[file] elements can be styled. In addition the button and field are treated as one element so there is no way to style the button. Hence the invisible element workaround.