# input type File Alternative button using JQuery click function

Tags: jquery, file-upload, input, click

I was trying to make a custom file upload button using the JQuery click function as seen here.

```
onclick="$('input[name=thumbfile]').click()"

<input id="thumbfile" name="thumbfile" type="file" value="upload" class="input" onchange="this.form.submit();"/>
```

Works fine in Safari but not in Firefox.

Any ideas.

Marvellous

Comment: Access to the `click()` event on a file selector is going to be limited severely by security restrictions. There are other workarounds, hang on....

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5191375/a-file-input-button-for-all-browsers-is-this-possible

Answer (score 0):

Firefox 3.6 doesn't support script clicking the file input element. Firefox 4 does allow it assuming that it's not blocked by its popup blocker; you'll be OK if you're just redirecting the click from another element.