# customizing file upload to look same in all browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, file-upload

How do I customize the file upload,

```
<input type="file" />
```

To look the same in all browsers?
I want to invoke file browser on clicking on my custom styled button.

Comment: This will probably help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5191375/a-file-input-button-for-all-browsers-is-this-possible

Comment: There are probably a dozen threads on this very topic already.  Please make use of the search box on SO.

Comment: [please don't](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After thinking for half hour found a solution myself which just solves this problem.(Yes, I knew the answer when I posted this question, but wanted to see how others would solve this, and of course I want to share my solution with the rest)

Working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nagendra_rao/mXZhD/4/) example.

```
<input style="float:left; width:270px; height:25px;" id="path" name="path" disabled /> <!--disabled it, to avoid user from editing the file path-->
<input style="display:none;" type="file" id="photo-path" name="file" placeholder="" /> <!-- hide the default input type='file' coz its ugly :) -->

<button type="submit" onclick="document.getElementById('photo-path').click(); return false;">Browse</button>  <!-- but call hidden input type='file' when user clicks on your custom browse button,  -->
```

This is the JQuery code: (to copy file path to your custom field)

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $('input[name="file"]').change(function(){
        var fileName = $(this).val();
        $('input[name="path"]').val(fileName);
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can overload the style on a upload button yourself by setting the opacity of the file upload to 0 and putting a div on top with the style you want. e.g.

```
    <input style="opacity:0; position: fixed;" onchange="openfile(event)" type="file">
    <div class="icon">Open</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is to hide the real input and replace it with a button.

```
$('input[type=file]').each(function(index,input){

     var button = $("<button class='file_btn'>Upload File</button>");
     $(input).before(button);
     $(input).css({position:'absolute',top:'-1000px'});

     button.click(function(){
         $(input).trigger('click');
     });

});
```

A working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KQhGR/1/

Answer (score -1):

Your best bet for something like this is to use a plugin like [Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/) to not only style the upload button consistently but add a progress bar adn multiple file uploads.

Unfortunately there isn't a reliable way (that I know of) to style file uploads consistently across all browsers.  It's one of those controls front end developers don't like to talk about.

Comment: There is a reliable way to do this cross-browser.  Many file upload libraries accomplish this already with a bit of CSS and javascript.