# Same look n feel for Input type=file

Tags: javascript, html, css, file-upload

I am using input file html control onto my web page and it is not giving a consistent look across all browsers. Is it possible to have same look n feel across all browsers. I need to look it like it is showing up for Google Chrome.
**Note: The solutions should work with multiple files e.g multiple="true"** 
This is how i am using file control on my MVC view

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FilesToUpload, new { type = "file", multiple = "true" })
```

[image]

Comment: Try the accepted answer from this SO post => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5191375/a-file-input-button-for-all-browsers-is-this-possible

Comment: Thanks. But that does not work properly with multiple="true" . I am using that control for multiple files. I will update the question as well.